# Submitting FileInputStream via ExecutorService

Tags: java, thread-safety, executorservice, callable

After using [this](https://github.com/briansjavablog/multi-threading-with-executorservice/blob/master/src/main/java/com/briansjavablog/concurrency/threads/ExecutorServiceCallableSample.java) as a guide I'm trying to send a FileInputStream to two APIs concurrently, if either of them fails we error out.
I have two [callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)s

```
    private void submitCallablesWithExecutor(final FileInputStream content)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
    ExecutorService executorService = null;

    try {
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        //send to api1
        final Future<String> futureOne = executorService.submit(new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                final String returnedValue = implOne.storeContent(content)
                return returnedValue;
            }
        });
        //send to api2
        final Future<String> futureTwo = executorService.submit(new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                final String returnedValue = implTwo.storeContent(content);
                return returnedValue;
            }
        });

        final String valueOne = futureOne.get(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        final String valueTwo = futureTwo.get(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } finally {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

within api2s implementation it tries to calculate the filesize with the below method

```
    protected Long calculateFilesize(InputStream data) throws StoreException {
    try {
        return (long) data.available();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error determining filesize of InputStream");
        throw new StoreException( e);
    }
}
```

I get the following error during data.available()

> java.io.IOException: Stream Closed

I suspect at some point the stream is being closed and at this point it fails to read it.
Any advice would be highly appreciated.

It's worth noting that the method that calls submitCallablesWithExecutor(content) is surrounded with a [try with resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). I wonder if it's auto closing the Stream?

```
    try (final FileInputStream content = new FileInputStream(tmpFile)) {
    submitCallablesWithExecutor(content)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It hard to tell without seeing more code of the tasks. This is one possible scenario for the closed stream. The javadoc for `executorService.shutdown();` says:

```
This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution.
```

If your first task take longer than 4 seconds to run you will get `TimeoutException` when calling `futureOne.get(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` which you don't catch so it leads to your own try with resource closing the FileInputStream. However the second callable might still be running in the executor service so could get this `java.io.IOException: Stream Closed` exception.

You could fix by using `future.get()` which blocks on first task completion, but it sounds like you don't want this, so it's better to cleanly shut down your service thread.

Try adding `executorService.awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` after `shutdown()` and catch the `TimeoutException` and handle appropriately to ensure the second task exits cleanly in this timeout/error situation, such as using latch or flags to notify to end the task.